# Throwing ResponseStatusException(404) results in response status 401 (with "Failure in @ExceptionHandler")

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I have this code in a service

```
val user = userRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow { UsernameNotFoundException("User with id $id was not found.") }
```

and in a controller

```
@ExceptionHandler
    fun handleUsernameNotFoundException(e: UsernameNotFoundException) {
        throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.localizedMessage)
    }
@PreAuthorize("somecheck('PUT user/{id}') || othercheck(#id)")
@PutMapping("/{id}")
fun update(@PathVariable id: UUID, @RequestBody @Valid data: Data) =
    service.update(id, data)
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the handler or the service (or sysout something) it clearly does execute. Despite of this, the response is 401 Unauthorized. Obviously the request IS authorized because if I pass a correct UUID I can update data.

Meanwhile in logs:

```
2020-12-16 12:54:43.751  WARN 16396 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.heilatech.customerportal.user.api.UserController#handleUsernameNotFoundException(UsernameNotFoundException)

org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND "User with id 53b522db-857a-4535-bddb-d1da3f3eeea4 was not found."
    at ...UserController.handleUsernameNotFoundException(UserController.kt:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at ....UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2f4c321e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at ....UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2918f47.handleUsernameNotFoundException(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:407) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1300) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1111) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! It seems that you cannot throw another exception inside ExceptionHandler. The correct way is

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(UsernameNotFoundException::class)
fun handleUsernameNotFoundException() {
    // nothing to do
}
```